# How to display Popunder - Window blur not working on Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have checked through a number of similar questions from the past. There have been quite a few suggestions from back then (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400086/window-blur-not-working-with-firefox-4), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255686/jquery-window-focus-blur-events-not-triggering-works-in-firefox-and-chrome) ). I am now required to build an application that needs to show a popunder window (this is not an advertisement, but part of the site's utility).

I tried all the suggestions from there, but it doesn't seem to work any longer. Is there a way someone can help me out with how sites like setmp3.com continue to show popunder ads? I am unable to find the actual script in the source

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't investigate the source either because setmp3.com is gone.