# Jquery window blur and focus on IE

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to do the following

```
$(window).bind("blur", function() {
    hasfocus = false;
  });

  $(window).bind("focus", function() {
    hasfocus = true;
  });
```

Works on Chrome and FF, but not on IE. When I click on any html element in an IE window, window blur gets invoked.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: This now works in IE11. As of today anyway (IE v11.0.9600.18524)

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer 8 you would have to use events `focusout` and `focusin` on `document` instead of `window`.

Full answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5556858/295687